# OR operator comparing None and bool

Tags: python

I found a particular bug in a piece of a function of mine, where the order of the args for the bitwise comparison OR seems to matter:

```
In: None or False
Out: False

In: False or None
Out: None
```

Checked this using Python 2.7.2 and IPython 0.10.2.

I can ensure that, in case of one element being None, making sure he's the first arg of the comparison, like this

```
if a==None:
    a or b
else:
    b or a
```

But could anyone please explain me why changing the order in an OR comparison would affect the output? Is this particular to Python?

Thanks.

Comment: It`s the shortcut behaviour of the boolean operator `or`. If the first operand is evaluated to `false` the second will be returned.

Comment: `or` is neither a bitwise operator nor a comparison operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From typing `help("or")`:

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is true, its
>       value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value
>       is returned.

In `None or False`, None isn't true, so False is returned.

In `False or None`, False isn't true, so None is returned.

Answer (score 1):

DSM has explained what the `or` operator does. Are you expecting the result to be a boolean, so that `None or False` or `False or None` is always `False`? If so, then you need to be explicit about it and use either `bool(None or False)`, or if you had a lot of them to check, then `any([None, False])` etc...

Comment: If you're `or`ing many values then surely you want `any`, not `all`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes - not sure where `all` came from there. Good spot - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a language where the order of the logical operator `or` does *not* matter, unless you have seen a langage where that is the case, the behaviour of python is normal.

`or` processes statements from left-to-right until one of them is True(or it gets to the end).

`and` processes statements from left-to-right until one of them is False (or it gets to the end).

The bitwise or operator (in Python, as in most languages) is a pipe '|'.